# How can I use NServiceBus.Configure to interrogate the container at runtime to get an instance of a class implementing a given interface?

Tags: c#, nservicebus

I am currently using NSB's container to register my dependencies like this:

```
public class Configuration : INeedInitialization
{
    public void Init()
    {
        Configure.Instance.Configurer.ConfigureComponent<ClassNameThatImplementsAnInterface>(DependencyLifecycle.InstancePerCall);
    }
}
```

at runtime, I want to interrogate the NSB container (I'm using the default container, autofac) to get the instance of a class defined in the Configuration class...

I know there is a way to find out if the container has a component at runtime:

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.HasComponent<ClassNameThatImplementsAnInterface>();
```

is something like this available?

```
Configure.Instance.Configurer.GetInstanceOfImplementingClass<IAmTheInterfaceThatIsBeingImplementedByTheClassIWantAnInstanceOf>();
```

???

Not too sure. The .Configurer seems to not have a very extensive API. I was poking around Configure.Instance a bit more as well, but haven't found anything yet.

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 1):

All you should need to do is inject the interface in your class and that should resolve.
NServiceBus automatically registers all the interfaces a class implements.

If you want to use the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) instead then all you need to do is `Configure.Instance.Builder.Build<IAmTheInterfaceThatIsBeingImplementedByTheClassIWantAnInstanceOf>()`